# MetaDataException was unhandled by user

Tags: c#, angularjs, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

This is my code, I get MetadataException was unhandled by user.

> An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException'
>   occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Hope someone can help me, thanks!

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult UserRegistration(User u)
    {
       string message = "";
            //Here we will save data to the database
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                using (barometerDBEntities1 dc = new barometerDBEntities1())
                {
                    //check username available
                    var user = dc.Users.Where(a => a.Username.Equals(u.Username)).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (user == null)
                    {
                        //Save here
                        dc.Users.Add(u);
                        dc.SaveChanges();
                        message = "Success";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        message = "Username not available!";
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                message = "Failed!";
            }
            return new JsonResult { Data = message,  JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What line does the error occur on? You should probably add some more context to this question.

Comment: It occurs in:                     var user = dc.Users.Where(a => a.Username.Equals(u.Username)).FirstOrDefault();